# How to define destination for an append query Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, inner-join

I'm trying to append two tables in MS Access at the moment. This is my SQL View of my Query at the moment:

```
INSERT INTO MainTable
SELECT 
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.University = Table2.University;
```

Where "University" is the only field name that *would* have similarities between the two tables. When I try and run the query, I get this error:

```
Query must have at least one destination field.
```

I assumed that the `INSERT INTO MainTable` portion of my SQL was defining the destination, but apparently I am wrong. How can I specify my destination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must select something from your select statement.

```
INSERT INTO MainTable
SELECT col1, col2
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.University = Table2.University;
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides [Luke Ford's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29103554/6884) *(which is correct)*, there's another gotcha to consider:

MS Access *(at least Access 2000, where I just tested it)* seems to match the columns by name.
In other words, when you execute the query from Luke's answer:

```
INSERT INTO MainTable
SELECT col1, col2
FROM ...
```

...MS Access assumes that `MainTable` has two columns named `col1` and `col2`, and tries to insert `col1` from your query into `col1` in `MainTable`, and so on.

**If the column names in `MainTable` are different, you need to specify them in the `INSERT` clause.**

Let's say the columns in `MainTable` are named `foo` and `bar`, then the query needs to look like this:

```
INSERT INTO MainTable (foo, bar)
SELECT col1, col2
FROM ...
```

Comment: This, as well as Luke's answer are extremely helpful. I wish I could accept both because they go hand-in-hand nicely.

Answer (score 0):

As other users have mentioned, your `SELECT` statement is empty. If you'd like to select more that just `col1, col2`, however, that is possible. If you want to select all columns in your two tables that are to be appended, you can use `SELECT *`, which will select everything in the tables.